# Where to get all pylint warning/error codes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint

Is there a place where I can get all `pylint` codes that are used for warning/error messages?

When I tried searching the `pylint` site for something like "C0114" (missing-module-docstring) I get no search results:

[image]

Where can I find all of these?

Looking in the code itself, it seems like they are scattered throughout all the files, so it would be nice to have a nice table showing all the possible codes if there's something like that possible:

```
.//pylint/checkers/strings.py:            "W1401": (
.//pylint/checkers/strings.py:            "W1402": (
.//pylint/checkers/strings.py:            "W1404": (
.//pylint/checkers/strings.py:            "W1405": (
.//pylint/extensions/empty_comment.py:    "R2044": (
.//pylint/extensions/broad_try_clause.py: "W0717": (
.//pylint/extensions/docparams.py:        "W9005": (
.//pylint/extensions/docparams.py:        "W9006": (
.//pylint/extensions/docparams.py:        "W9008": (
.//pylint/extensions/docparams.py:        "W9010": (
...etc
```

Answer (score 9):

There are two ways you might want to get this:

1. To list all messages you can do:

   ```
   $ pylint --list-msgs
   :exception-escape (W1661): *Using an exception object that was bound by...
   :comprehension-escape (W1662): *Using a variable that was bound inside a...
   ```
2. If you know the name of a specific message and want to look up its code you can do the above with the help of grep:

   ```
   $ pylint --list-msgs |grep trailing-newlines
   :trailing-newlines (C0305): *Trailing newlines*
   ```

Comment: `pylint --help-msg=<msg id>` gives a more thorough explanation than what is found in `--list-msgs`

Answer (score 6):

PyLint documentation is almost as bad as its diagnostics - for PyLint 1.6.5 (which is ancient btw) the codes seem to be listed in [Pylint features](https://docs.pylint.org/en/1.6.0/features.html) - likewise for [latest release](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/technical_reference/features.html).

Comment: thanks I added a couple examples too which was good enough for my small use-case (disabling a few where I couldn't find their codes)

Comment: PyLint v2.9.3: https://docs.pylint.org/en/v2.9.3/technical_reference/features.html
PyLint latest: https://docs.pylint.org/en/latest/technical_reference/features.html

Comment: I also found the latest release from pycqa.org, which is what Antti Haapala suggests, listing all the messages I was looking for and which I couldn't find anywehere else: pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/technical_reference/features.html. That allowed me to tweak my .pylintc file to add a few exceptions I didn't want the linter to pick up on. So Antii's answer gets my upvote